# Can you use HTML5 File Api or other means to generate thumbnail from Photoshop PSD?

Tags: html, fileapi, psd

Is there any way to generate a thumbnail image from a Photoshop PSD on a Web page?  Here is what I'm trying to do:

1. User drags a PSD onto a page (PSD is over 600megs in size)
2. Without having to upload entire PSD, web page is able to generate a thumbnail image of the PSD
3. Page saves thumbnail only to back end.

Possible?

Comment: Gimp should be able to do that. I'm not sure about a web browser thought.

Comment: you can have a look at https://github.com/won21kr/psd.js-1 but I'm not sure about the browser support.